# jQuery AJAX not working on iPhone safari

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, ajax

So I am making an Ajax call using jQuery and it works fine all desktop browsers and on chrome in android however it doesn't work in Safari on iOS any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (function($){
      function processForm( e ){
        var callid = $('.callid').val();
        var pin = $('.pin').val();
        var urlFinal = callid+'/'+pin;
          $.ajax({
              url: 'http://URLHERE/getHash/' + urlFinal,
              dataType: 'text',
              type: 'get',
              contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                    var urlResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log("WORKS! " + urlResponse.streamFileUrl);
                    $('.overlay').show();
                    playVideo(urlResponse);

              },
              error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                  console.log('INCORRECT DETAILS ');
                  $('.incorrect').show()
              }
          });
          e.preventDefault();
      }
      $('#form').submit( processForm );

  })(jQuery);

})
```

Comment: Please describe what exactly isn't working.

Comment: What does 'It doesn't work' mean in this context?

Comment: Well the Ajax call doesnt seem to run at all, its hard to debug without a console but not getting any errors, just not running

Answer (score 0):

At LEAST unwrap your code from the superfluous extra load handler, Only rarely do you need an IIFE inside the load handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){  // load handler 
  (function($){  // remove
```

move the preventDefault to where the submit will stop if the rest of the code is failing and remove unnecessary junk:

```
dataType: 'text', // jQUery will figure this out based on response
type: 'get', // default
contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', // only needed for POST

var urlResponse = JSON.parse(data); // if text is left out, JSON is returned
```

Here is a shorter and cleaner version

```js
$(function() { // shorter version of $(document).ready(function
  $('#form').on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // belongs HERE
    var callid = $('.callid').val();
    var pin = $('.pin').val();
    var urlFinal = callid + '/' + pin;
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://URLHERE/getHash/' + urlFinal,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jQxhr) {
        console.log("WORKS! " + data.streamFileUrl); // is already JSON
        $('.overlay').show();
        playVideo(urlResponse);
      },
      error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('INCORRECT DETAILS ');
        $('.incorrect').html(errorThrown).show()
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the refractor I had to leave dataType: 'text', otherwise it JSON.parse(data); wouldn't work

Comment: so don't use JSON parse. If it is JSON it will come as JSON